Difference between phrases for "absorbed in"/"infatuated in"/"indulge in"
I tried limiting this list to words I have heard in conversations and in media in colloquial contexts, although I am not sure they are all suitable for conversation. All these words I believe have to do with being either absorbed in some activity or being infatuated with someone or something, which aren't exactly the same concept but I believe grouping them is useful because "absorbed in x" or "into x" in English I think can occasionally refer to both contexts, i.e. "I am absorbed in her beauty". There also are words that may be better translated as "addicted to", but this phrase again I would say can fall under English "absorbed in".
You find many different words when you search "absorbed in" in the dictionary, so I think differentiating them is useful.
I will try to list them from what I think is most colloquial to least colloquial although I am not certain:

はまる/沼る  [～に]
These seem to be the most colloquial to mean "I am into X" typically used for hobbies or interests, and I don't think they differ much. There's probably a nuance that it is somewhat bad to be "into" the marked thing considering each verb being associated with being "stuck in" something.
夢中になっている  [～が]
The most common and seems to safely be used for both interests and also duties like work and research.
熱中する [～に]
I have a feeling that this word is essentially the same as 夢中になる but might be a little stronger or may be used for more long term activities.
没頭する/没入する [～に]
These seem to mean the same thing "immerse in", with the former more common, again very similar to 夢中になる but I feel like it has a larger nuance of putting everything else to the side.
病みつきになる [～が]
Closest to "addicted", but I think this is very similar to はまる/沼る in how it is used, with probably a stronger a maybe more negative nuance.
のめり込む [～に]
I have heard that this word is used like 夢中になる most of the time but may be more likely used for getting involved with something, in my dictionary it is used with [悪の道に～].
凝る [～に]
This has a nuance of being very particular of the thing you are "into" because it has a separate usage that is similar to こだわる. So I think if you say 食べ物に凝っている it means you aren't just interested in food but also may imply you frequently compare recipes, personally know owners of local restaurants, or are very particular about taste.
溺れる [～に]
Much more like "infatuated" or "wallow in", so if you say 恋におぼれる "drowning in/with love", it definitely has a negative and strong nuance.
ふける [～に]
Similar to English "indulge", so the common 空想にふける implies that you are absorbed in daydreams to a probably irregular degree. I think 浸る basically means the same thing.
埋没する [～に]
Outside of meanings of "being buried" and "becoming obscure", this seems to coincide with 没頭する, being used in contexts of being "wrapped up" in one's daily routine and such.
身を窶す{やつす} [～に]
Another common meaning of this is to "change one's appearance so you aren't noticed by others", but another meaning seems to mean to to be absorbed in something that is hopeless as one of my dictionaries defines this as:
やせるほど思い悩む。「恋に身を―す」
I am unsure if there is any etymological connection to these meanings, perhaps it has to do with the specific usage of 瘦せるほど.

In English, I would go as far to say that "I am into X" can cover the majority of these situations. I am very likely off the mark on these definitions but I would like to know their nuances nonetheless.

I think the English phrases you describe cover quite a range of meanings, which makes it hard to sort out a coherent question here.


はまる/沼る [～に] This indicates certain level of not being able to stop/quit, though in practice this is not meant so seriously. 沼る is a bit different IMO. It suggests you are unable to resolve a tricky situation, rather than being into something.

夢中になっている [～が]: Both 熱中する and 夢中になる implies you are so deeply focused that you don't perceive the outside world (you lose track of time, don't notice if somebody says something to you. 熱中する is indeed stronger.

没頭する/没入する: Similar to 夢中になる, agree with you that it has a larger nuance of putting everything else to the side.

病みつきになる [～が] Agree with what you wrote, tho I don't feel 沼る is used for being into something. 病みつき is also more often used for stuff you consume, like food, drink, experience like skydiving etc.

のめり込む [～に]: Agreed with what you wrote. It'd be used for activities, and not food/drinks (unlike 病みつき).

凝る [～に]: Agreed with what you wrote. If pronounced "koru" also suggests those particularness is somehow amateurish and possibly shallow (e.g. novice buying very expensive equipment). You will never describe a professional to be koru, whereas kodawaru is ok.

溺れる [～に]: Agreed with what you wrote. It means you are no longer effective in whatever you are doing.

ふける [～に] 浸る: IMO this is exclusively used when you entertain thoughts in your head. Agreed with what you wrote.

埋没する [～に]: Agreed to what you wrote, tho IMO it's used when it's voluntary situation (not that you are involuntarily buried). 没頭する is definitely voluntary.

身を窶やつす [～に]: IMO this describes being exhausted, not caring yourself adequately due to concerns/sorrow/disease etc. Wouldn't describe it as being indulged


